# How to fix ' for i in range (0, random(2,5) + 1):'

Tags: python, syntax

When I run this code as a part of something else it gives me the following error:

> range() integer end argument expected, got float

I don't know what to do so I haven't really tried anything.. This is my code:

```
for i in range (0, random(2,5) + 1):
```

Comment: try turning the float into an integer, that's what the error message is saying, right?

Comment: `random()` takes no arguments. Maybe you meant `randint`?

Comment: what is `random` in your example? Did you define it yourself? Please add that to your question

Comment: use `int()` in `range(0, int(random(2,5)) + 1)`  or import `randint` and use `range(0, randint(2,5) + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

the range() function expect integers, but your random() return a float.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided;

`random()` does not accept arguments and gives you float numbers and `range()` accepts integers not float values.

You can use either `randint` or `randrange` for your problem.

```
from random import randint,randrange

for i in range (0, randint(2,5) + 1):
    print(i)

for i in range (0, randrange(2,5) + 1):
    print(i)
```